# Counting how many times series crossed within x amount of bars

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to count how many times series crossed each other for the last 150 bars, below code gives me completely random numbers that don't make any sense. Does ta.cross() function not handle the [] operator?? That's the only thing that comes to my mind.

```
var crossCount = 0

for i = 0 to 150
    if ta.cross(series1[i], series2[i])
        crossCount += 1

plotchar(crossCount, "Cross Count", "", location = location.top)

//zero the cross count at the end of execution
crossCount := 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to use certain functions within local scopes such as for loops or if blocks. There is another easier way to accomplish what you want.

```
int crossed = ta.cross(series1, series2) ? 1 : 0
int crossCount = math.sum(crossed, 150)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, works like charm, just had to remove the "int" declarations